# array.push() and .toFixed - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating program for generating random numbers using javascript.
While writing the code, I observed this strange behaviour;(Or atleast strange to me).

Variable are:

- M is Maximum of range in which random number has to be generated.(inclusive)
- m is Minimum of range in which random number has to be generated.(inclusive)
- q is Level of decimals; i.e, for 0.9, it is 1; for 0.09 and 0.99 it is 2 etc.
- q1 is 10^q; i.e., if q=1, q1=10; if q=2, q1=100 etc.

And somewhere among my codes:

```
array.push(m+(((Math.round(((Math.random()*(M-m)) + (Number.EPSILON))) * q1) / q1))).toFixed(q);
```

This worked perfectly as intended.
But then I realised .toFixed(q) is outside the array.push;
I mean it is like

```
array.push(/*some code here*/).toFixed(/*another code here*/);
```

Even though it is working as intended I am curious that whether array.push() has method .toFixed().
So when I put:

```
array.push((m+(((Math.round(((Math.random()(M-m)) + (Number.EPSILON))) * q1) / q1))).toFixed(q));
```

and `q=3` The result has last 3 digits as 0. For example:9.000.

So ultimately my questions are:

1. Why didn't my code work as intended when I put .toFixed() inside parenthesis of array.push()?
2. Does array.push() has a method .toFixed()?

Sorry for my English if something is wrong, English is not my native tongue.
You can see my full code here:
https://github.com/vinob4u/vinob4u.github.io/blob/main/BlockRandom.html

Comment: The `.push()` method returns a number (the new length of the array).

Comment: This `toFixed` does nothing because it's result is never assigned to anything

Comment: Also `Math.round()` returns an integer, so everything past the decimal point will be 0. If you multiply by `q1` and then divide by `q1`, the value does not change because `q1/q1` is 1.

Comment: @Pointy Can't believe I have failed to notice this. Your comment along with answer by Quentin completes my understanding of what actually happened. Thanks a lot :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why didn't my code work as intended when I put .toFixed() inside parenthesis of array.push()?

The purpose of `toFixed` is to convert a number to a string with the specified number of decimal places.

You said `9..toFixed(3)` so it expressed `9` to three decimal places, which is `"9.000"`.

It's generally more useful when presenting numbers with a high degree of precision to something readable (e.g. `1.234567890.toFixed(3)` would be `"1.234"`).

You seem to want `9 / Math.pow(10, 3)`.

> Does array.push() has a method .toFixed()?

The return value of `array.push()` is a number (specifically *The new `length` property of the object upon which the method was called*).

Numbers have a `toFixed` method.